# How to handle an variable that returns null inside an Assert

Tags: c#, selenium, restsharp

I'm hustling around with selenium and having a little hard time with my Assert.
I have something like this.

```
_request = new RestRequest($"applications", Method.GET);
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppRoot[]>(_restClient.Execute(_request).Content);

var org = result.FirstOrDefault(a => a.orgNr.ToString() == "1337");

Assert.IsTrue((org.applicationType == type && org == null) ? true : false, "Failed" + type);
```

Now if `org.applicationType` match the **type** Assert is passing (true).

And if `var org = null`, I want the Assert to return false, with the message - **Failed type**

But here the assert is looking for the variable and fails with the classic
**System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance**

Any ideas on how this can be handled?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `org != null && org.applicationType` to get a null `org` to be false and to make sure `org.applicationType` is not evaluated when `org` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `?` [conditional access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) syntax will help you avoid the error message. This will handle the case where `org` is null:

```
Assert.IsTrue(org?.applicationType == type, "Failed" + type);
```

`org?.applicationType` is `null` if `org` is null, so this will work around the exception that is thrown. This statement asserts that `org?.applicationType == type`, so when `org` is `null` the comparison will be `null == type`. This returns false, thus failing the test if `org.applicationType` is null, and passing if `org.applicationType == type`.

Comment: yeah. now its handling the null value. But unfortunately If the Assert is true it also returning the failing message :|

Comment: You could also do `Assert.IsNotNull(org?.applicationType);`. But this doesn't actually check `type`. I think you should use `Assert.IsTrue(org?.applicationType == type);` -- I updated my answer and explanation.

Comment: @Christina. 
yeah awesome. now it works 
Thank you so much. The ? syntax will serve me very well :D